# ngrx effect class as injected services as undefined

Tags: ngrx-store, angular12

I have a ngrx effect defined a  below

```
@Injectable()
export class AmazingEffects {

createTodos$ = createEffect(this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(CREATE_TASK)
    .map(() => {
        console.log('called');
            return { type: 'OTHER'};
})));

constructor(private readonly actions$: Action) {
}
}
```

Due to some reason this.actions$ is undefined, and I spend 2 days figuring it out, did any one else had this kinda issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and I also spend 2 days figuring it out!

**old**

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**new**

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I update the tsconfig.json,set Strict mode ture and fix all the error; and then all right now.

Comment: Thanks... I will try this.. 
I just moved all my effect defination inside construtor, that fixed the issue ..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this also works.

```
export abstract class Wrapper {
  constructor(protected readonly actions$: Actions) {}
}
export class Effects extends Wrapper {
  constructor(actions$: Actions) {
    super(actions$);
  }
}
```

or

```
export class Effects extends class {
  constructor(protected readonly actions$: Actions) {}
} {
  constructor(
    actions$: Actions,
  ) {
    super(actions$);
  }
}
```